# Making a subclass be able to use the parent class's functions?

Tags: c++, sfml

I want the struct MenuItem to be able to used HighlightRectOutline. How do I do this?

Text.h

```
    class Text {

public:
             ....

    void Text::highlightRectOutline(sf::RenderWindow &window, sf::Color color);

    struct MenuItem {
        public:
            Menu::MenuResult action;
    };
```

HighlightRectOutline:

```
void highlightRectOutline(sf::RenderWindow &window, sf::Color color) {
    sf::RectangleShape outlineRect;

    sf::Vector2f size(Text::getWidth(), Text::getHeight());

    outlineRect.setSize(size);
    outlineRect.setPosition(Text::getPosition());

    outlineRect.setFillColor(sf::Color::Transparent);

    outlineRect.setOutlineColor(color);
    outlineRect.setOutlineThickness(5);

    window.draw(outlineRect);
}
```

THIS FUNCTION IS FIXED. SCROLL DOWN
Menu.h

```
class Menu {

    public:
        static enum MenuResult { Exit, Options, Back, ChangeResolution, Play, Nothing };

        MenuResult showMMenu(sf::RenderWindow &window);
        MenuResult showOMenu(sf::RenderWindow &window);

    private:
        MenuResult getMenuResponse(sf::RenderWindow &window);
        MenuResult handleClick(int x, int y);
        Menu::MenuResult Menu::handleButtonHover(sf::RenderWindow &window, Text::MenuItem menuItem, int x, int y);
        std::list<Text::MenuItem> menuItems;

};
```

handleButtonHover:

```
Menu::MenuResult Menu::handleButtonHover(sf::RenderWindow &window, Text::menuItem menuItem, int x, int y) {

    sf::Color color(255, 122, 40);

    std::list<Text::MenuItem>::iterator it;

    for(it = menuItems.begin(); it != menuItems.end(); it++)
    {
        sf::floatRect menuItemRect = (*it).getRect();

        if( menuItemRect.contains(x, y)) 
            menuItem.highlightRectOutline(window, color);
    }

    return Nothing;

}
```

This can't use getRect or menuItem.

Help would be dearly appreciated.

Comment: `MenuItem` isn't a subclass. It's a nested class.

Comment: @sftrabbit: Hehe, "subclass" is such a terrible, terrible choice of word that this mistake is almost excusable...

Answer (score 0):

Apart from not being a subclass as sftrabbit already mentioned, you should declare your base-class' methods as protected. In that way they are visible to subclasses.